# Sort HashMap data by value

Tags: rust

I want to sort HashMap data by value in Rust (e.g., when counting character frequency in a string).

The Python equivalent of what I’m trying to do is:

```
count = {}
for c in text:
    count[c] = count.get('c', 0) + 1

sorted_data = sorted(count.items(), key=lambda item: -item[1])

print('Most frequent character in text:', sorted_data[0][0])
```

My corresponding Rust code looks like this:

```
// Count the frequency of each letter
let mut count: HashMap<char, u32> = HashMap::new();
for c in text.to_lowercase().chars() {
    *count.entry(c).or_insert(0) += 1;
}

// Get a sorted (by field 0 ("count") in reversed order) list of the
// most frequently used characters:
let mut count_vec: Vec<(&char, &u32)> = count.iter().collect();
count_vec.sort_by(|a, b| b.1.cmp(a.1));

println!("Most frequent character in text: {}", count_vec[0].0);
```

Is this idiomatic Rust?  Can I construct the `count_vec` in a way so that it would consume the HashMaps data and owns it (e.g., using `map()`)?  Would this be more idomatic?

Comment: I guess you mean 'by field 1'? (in your comment)

Comment: shouldn't that be or_insert(1) so you count 1 in the case where you don't increment? Or does or_insert() return the count also which is then incremented. I see other examples using or_insert(1) (and they maybe wrong!?)

Comment: I was thinking: opcode_usage.entry(opname)
            .and_modify(|count| *count += 1)
            .or_insert(1);

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Is this idiomatic Rust?

There's nothing particularly *unidiomatic*, except *possibly* for the unnecessary full type constraint on `count_vec`; you could just use

```rust
let mut count_vec: Vec<_> = count.iter().collect();
```

It's not difficult from context to work out what the full type of `count_vec` is.  You could *also* omit the type constraint for `count` *entirely*, but then you'd have to play shenanigans with your integer literals to have the correct value type inferred.  That is to say, an explicit annotation is eminently reasonable in this case.

The *other* borderline change you could make *if you feel like it* would be to use `|a, b| a.1.cmp(b.1).reverse()` for the sort closure.  The `Ordering::reverse` method just reverses the result so that less-than becomes greater-than, and vice versa.  This makes it slightly more obvious that you *meant* what you wrote, as opposed to accidentally transposing two letters.

> Can I construct the count_vec in a way so that it would consume the HashMaps data and owns it?

Not in any meaningful way.  Just because `HashMap` is using memory doesn't mean that memory is in any way compatible with `Vec`.  You could use `count.into_iter()` to *consume* the `HashMap` and move the elements out (as opposed to iterating over pointers), but since both `char` and `u32` are trivially copyable, this doesn't really gain you anything.

Answer (score 11):

This could be another way to address the matter without the need of an intermediary vector.

```
// Count the frequency of each letter
let mut count: HashMap<char, u32> = HashMap::new();
for c in text.to_lowercase().chars() {
    *count.entry(c).or_insert(0) += 1;
}

let top_char = count.iter().max_by(|a, b| a.1.cmp(&b.1)).unwrap();

println!("Most frequent character in text: {}", top_char.0);
```

Answer (score 6):

### use `BTreeMap` for sorted data

`BTreeMap` sorts its elements by `key` by default, therefore exchanging the place of your key and value and putting them into a `BTreeMap`

```rust
let count_b: BTreeMap<&u32,&char> = count.iter().map(|(k,v)| (v,k)).collect();
```

should give you a sorted map according to character frequency.
Some character of the same frequency shall be lost though. But if you only want the most frequent character, it does not matter.

You can get the result using

```rust
println!("Most frequent character in text: {}", count_b.last_key_value().unwrap().1);
```