# Sort a hashmap by values in rust

Tags: rust

In python its done this way:

```
>>> x = {1: 2, 3: 4, 4: 3, 2: 1, 0: 0}
>>> {k: v for k, v in sorted(x.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}

{0: 0, 2: 1, 1: 2, 4: 3, 3: 4}
```

How to sort a `HashMap` by values in rust?

My code so far:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut count: HashMap<String, u32>= HashMap::new();
    count.insert(String::from("A"), 5);
    count.insert(String::from("B"), 2);
    count.insert(String::from("C"), 11);
    count.insert(String::from("D"), 10);

    let highest = count.iter().max_by(|a, b| a.1.cmp(&b.1)).unwrap();

    println!("largest hash: {:?}", highest); // largest hash: ("C", 11)
}
```

Comment: Do you have code you tried so far and does not work?

Comment: Hash maps are not sorted in Rust, or in any language. They can't be. Python dictionaries appear sorted because they're not strictly speaking hash tables. They combine a vector of `(hash, key, value)` tuples with a hash table of indices into that vector: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-December/123028.html

Comment: @Jmb Python's dicts don't *appear* to be ordered, they absolutely are.

Comment: @Masklinn but they're not hash tables either. They _use_ a hash table internally, but they combine that hash table with a vector to get the ordering.

Comment: @Jmb which is technically correct and practically of no relevance, even less so given at no point did I deny that python's dicts are not strictly hashmap, I merely pointed out that dict doesn't "appear sorted" but *is ordered*, as in the language literally specifies this behaviour.

Comment: @Jmb and if you want to nitpick this to death, your comment also implies that the point of the dense array is the ordering, which is incorrect: the point of the dense array is better memory behaviour (better memory locality and lower memory usage), being naturally ordered was a useful side-effect, which is why the ordering was only specified in Python 3.7 despite the change having occurred in 3.6 (and even earlier in other implementations).

Comment: 'Sort a hashmap' is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 12):

Ya, sorted it by converting to vector:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut count: HashMap<String, u32>= HashMap::new();
    count.insert(String::from("A"), 5);
    count.insert(String::from("B"), 2);
    count.insert(String::from("C"), 11);
    count.insert(String::from("D"), 10);

    let mut hash_vec: Vec<(&String, &u32)> = count.iter().collect();
    println!("{:?}", hash_vec);
    hash_vec.sort_by(|a, b| b.1.cmp(a.1));

    println!("Sorted: {:?}", hash_vec); //Sorted: [("C", 11), ("D", 10), ("A", 5), ("B", 2)]
}
```

[Sort HashMap data by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34555837/sort-hashmap-data-by-value)

Answer (score 10):

Unlike Python's `dict`, Rust's "built-in" hashmap is not ordered, so sorting it has no effect.

If you need an ordered map for some reason, you should use [indexmap](https://docs.rs/indexmap/1.6.0/indexmap/). Alternatively, `BTreeMap` is *sorted* based on the key.

As you don't really present any sort of compelling use case it's hard to provide counsel though.

Comment: Sorry for not providing use case, I needed the N the highest values of the hash map, so, converting to vector solved the problem.